how to use createBrowserRouter in react + react router dom?
In my application I am using BrowserRouter component to render my routes or components, but I want to use loader functionality. My current approach I am not able to use that feature.
<BrowserRouter>
  <AppRoutes />
</BrowserRouter>

As suggested by below link I need to use createBrowserRouter function .
why loader function not called in react js?
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router
current way of routing.
export default function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<RequireAuth />}>
          <Route
            path={'/'}
            element={
              <React.Suspense
                fallback={<div>loading</div>}
                children={<Booking />}
              />
            }
          ></Route>
        </Route>
        <Route element={<RequireAuth />}>
          <Route
            path={'/app'}
            element={
              <React.Suspense
                fallback={<div>loading</div>}
                children={<App />}
              />
            }
          ></Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Layout>
  );
}

I am trying to refactor my routing using createBrowserRouter. I tried like this:
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    loader: () => {
      console.log('0000');
      return 'ss';
    },
    element: <RequireAuth />,
  },
  {
    path: '/app',
    loader: () => {
      console.log('0000');
      return 'ss';
    },
    element: <RequireAuth />,
  },
]);

How to render Booking and App components? How I will render children in createBrowserRouter approach any idea?
Here is code sandbox demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-6gg4ab?file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fmain.tsx,src%2Findex.css,src%2Froutes.tsx,src%2Flayout.tsx,src%2FRequireAuth.tsx,src%2Fbrowser-routes.tsx&terminal=dev

The createBrowserRouter function takes an array of RouteObject types

export interface NonIndexRouteObject {
  caseSensitive?: AgnosticNonIndexRouteObject["caseSensitive"];
  path?: AgnosticNonIndexRouteObject["path"];
  id?: AgnosticNonIndexRouteObject["id"];
  loader?: AgnosticNonIndexRouteObject["loader"];
  action?: AgnosticNonIndexRouteObject["action"];
  hasErrorBoundary?: AgnosticNonIndexRouteObject["hasErrorBoundary"];
  shouldRevalidate?: AgnosticNonIndexRouteObject["shouldRevalidate"];
  handle?: AgnosticNonIndexRouteObject["handle"];
  index?: false;
  children?: RouteObject[];
  element?: React.ReactNode | null;
  hydrateFallbackElement?: React.ReactNode | null;
  errorElement?: React.ReactNode | null;
  Component?: React.ComponentType | null;
  HydrateFallback?: React.ComponentType | null;
  ErrorBoundary?: React.ComponentType | null;
  lazy?: LazyRouteFunction<RouteObject>;
}

export type RouteObject = IndexRouteObject | NonIndexRouteObject;


The children property takes another array of RouteObject objects, so you can use this recursive structure to build up your routing hierarchy.
To convert the first code snippet using the BrowserRouter to the new Data Router syntax I suggest the following refactor that:

Converts Layout to a layout route component
Layout.tsx
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <div>
      Layout
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}


Renders a single layout route rendering RequireAuth, this makes for code that is a bit more DRY

Renders Booking and App on nested routes under the auth layout route
routes.tsx
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        element: <RequireAuth />,
        children: [
          {
            path: '/',
            loader: () => {
              console.log('0000');
              return 'ss';
            },
            element: (
              <React.Suspense
                fallback={<div>loading</div>}
                children={<Booking />}
              />
            ),
          },
          {
            path: '/app',
            loader: () => {
              console.log('0000');
              return 'ss';
            },
            element: (
              <React.Suspense
                fallback={<div>loading</div>}
                children={<App />}
              />
            ),
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);

export default router;


Update main.tsx to render a RouterProvider and the computed router instead of the BrowserRouter component
main.tsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import router from './routes';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);




To render children to any path you do this: Using Booking app as example child

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    loader: () => {
      console.log('0000');
      return 'ss';
    },
    element: <RequireAuth />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/Booking',
        element: <Booking />,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/app',
    loader: () => {
      console.log('0000');
      return 'ss';
    },
    element: <RequireAuth />,
  },
]);


You can find very illustrative examples on their documentation here https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial
